# Creating Beanstalk without an internet connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to make beanstalk instances not connect outside the VPC to public internet.

The problem is that, when I clear the outbound security group and actually block the internet access, it makes the instances not start properly and throw error "502 Bad Gateway", also the health status in beanstalk change to "unknown".

When I checked the system log I saw that the instance is trying to connect outside the VPC in the user data script.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using EB environment in a private subnet (no internet) is not that straight forward. The general consideration of how to do this are described in the **AWS docs**:

- [Using Elastic Beanstalk with Amazon VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/vpc.html#services-vpc-private)

For example, EB uses  `Network Time Protocol (NTP)` thus you have to have internet connectivity. Without that, as docs describe, there are **issues with Elastic Beanstalk health reporting**.

You also need to setup **VPC endpoints** for Elastic Beanstalk as well as the endpoints for other services (e.g. S3):

- [Using Elastic Beanstalk with VPC endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/vpc-vpce.html)

If you .ebextenstions install any packages from the internet, you need to ensure that you have properly setup **NAT gateway** or NAT instance.

The docs also provide example in CloudFormation [vpc-private.yaml](https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/cfn-templates/vpc-private.yaml) with exemplary setup for Internet gateway, NAT gateway, and route table.